# Get title of eclipse dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dialog

I want to create an Eclipse plugin, which lists me all eclipse dialog titles I have opened. For this purpose, I am learning how I can write Eclipse plugins.

But my question is: I wanted to get the title of a dialog, for example the "New Java Class" dialog. How can I make this? And is it possible to get further information, for example the name for the new Java Class, which is entered in the dialog field.

Answer (score 1):

The title displayed as the dialog window title is accessed by the `getText()` method of the `Shell` for the dialog.

There is no general way to access any of the fields in a dialog from outside of the dialog. Some dialogs may provide `getXXX` methods but most do not. You can look at the controls in the dialog to try and find the information but this is going to be tricky and easily broken if the dialog is changed.

Since many of the dialog classes are internal to Eclipse this may also be violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: How can I get the object for the search dialog at any given time? Or more generic: How can I get the object of a view or a dialog at any given time? Can you give me an example source code somewhere?

Comment: Dialogs normally block the UI thread and non-UI threads can't access the UI information so getting this information could be challenging. I don't know of anything that tries to do this.